# plotting geom_segment using a functional form for the interpolation using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot segments of start->end using ggplot2 with a custom function for the interpolation. I know the functional form of the field and I would like the segments to follow that. I think this simple example will help explain:

```r
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.2.2
tibble(
    x = seq(-pi, pi, .01),
    x0 = x*.5,
    x1 = x*1.5,
    random_shift = runif(length(x)),
    y0 = sin(x0) + random_shift,
    y1 = sin(x1) + random_shift
) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x0, y0, xend = x1, yend = y1)) +
    geom_segment()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

In this simple case, I am trying to plot the local function for each point (define for a range around it) but `geom_segment` does linear extrapolation between start and end. I could use `geom_curve` but then I would need to estimate local curvature (and this will not be very feasible for more complex functions e.g., higher order polynomial, non-linear fields, etc). Alternatively I could use `stat_function` but it always extrapolates over the x-axis.

Is there a way to define the interpolation using a functional form (e.g. `~f(.x, theta)` where `theta` are local function parameters) for the interpolation? In this case the functional form is the sine function.
Noteworthy, I would like to avoid producing large number of points with small linear interpolations to approximate the functional form.

Comment: I'm not quite sure whether you can 'avoid producing large number of points with small linear interpolations' - this is exactly what `curve()`, `geom_curve()`, `stat_function()`, etc. all do (there are a few graphical primitives for drawing e.g. Bezier curves, but almost all of the 'curve-drawing' that R does is in fact computing and drawing lots of linear interpolating segments ... (e.g. you can see [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/main/R/stat-function.r#L55-L82) the guts of `stat_function()` ...)